# VSPackage, how to add a pointer type variable to a CodeClass

Tags: c#, vsix, vspackage, vs-extensibility

I'm working on my own vspackage.
I can add variables to my class by using AddVariable.

The "cl" is a class named "TestPage", and following code insert "TestPage mTestVariable" to my class.

```
CodeClass cl = element as CodeClass;
cl.AddVariable("mTestVariable", cl, 0, EnvDTE.vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPrivate);
```

Now I want to insert a pointer to my class, like this:

```
TestPage* mTestVariable;
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can just add variable named "*mTestVariable".

Like this:

```
cl.AddVariable("*mTestVariable", cl, 0, EnvDTE.vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPrivate);
```